# Importing/restoring contacts from HTC's .vef file on other devices

Tags: contacts, backup, htc

I have backed up my contacts from the HTC device, and I got the .vef file.

How to use the .vef file in Samsung mobile? I can't open the .vef file. Is it possible to convert .vef to .vcf? Or are any other methods available to convert the file?

Comment: Use vef file opener trial version

Comment: As far as I know you can use a .vef file to import contacts to your Google account using your PC. Open the contacts section of your Google account on a desktop browser and you'll see the import contacts option at the bottom of the left sidebar.

Once you've done that just sync your Google contacts on any of your Android devices and your contacts will appear. And in future make sure you save new contacts as a Google contact instead of on your phone memory, it makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Above solution importing to Google contacts does not work out. as google does not support this format. i have tried it.

Comment: I wonder why HTC used this unknown file format for exporting contacts. This file is not in textual format and is not viewable in text editors. I can confirm that above solution doesn't work, too.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and only if you still have access to your HTC device: when exporting the contacts, you can choose not to encrypt them. The contacts are exported to a .vcf file then.